No module named 'src'
I have a python project. The folder structure is like the following:
src
 ┣ utils
 ┃ ┣ custom_pow.py
 ┃ ┣ equation.py
 ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┣ app.py
 ┗ __init__.py

custom_pow.py
class Pow:
    def __init__(self,a,n):
        self.a = a
        self.n = n
    def pow(self):
        out = self.a ** self.n
        return out

equation.py
from src.utils.custom_pow import Pow
class CustFormula:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def apbwsq(self):
        ap = Pow(self.a,2)
        bp = Pow(self.b,2)
        out = (ap.pow()) + (2*self.a*self.b) + (bp.pow())
        return out
    def apbwcub(self):
        aap = Pow(self.a,3)
        bbp = Pow(self.b,3)
        ap = Pow(self.a,2)
        bp = Pow(self.b,2)
        out = (aap.pow()) + (bbp.pow()) + 3*ap.pow()*self.b + 3*bp.pow()*self.a
        return out

app.py
from src.utils.equation import CustFormula

p = CustFormula(2,3)
out = p.apbwsq()

print(f"(2+3)^2 = {out}")

I am pretty new to Python packaging. As per my understanding if we put init.py it will be considered as a module.
But while I am running the app.py from the src folder I am getting the below error:
File "********\module-test\src\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src.utils.equation import CustFormula
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Please help me to solve this.

You would generally not include src. in the path of your module; instead, your project would be configured to search for modules inside the src folder. However, this depends on how exactly your project is configured (i.e. how you are calling your code inside __main__.py, and how your environment is set up).

Since app.py is located directly inside the src directory, you need to adjust the import statement to correctly reference CustFormula from equation.py.
from utils.equation import CustFormula

In equation.py, adjust the import statement for Pow to correctly reference custom_pow.py in the same utils package.
from .custom_pow import Pow

In Python 3.3 and later, you don't strictly need __init__.py files to define a package structure, but they can be useful for explicit initialization or for ensuring compatibility with older Python versions, you can try to remove it and the code will still work as expected.
